# REACT Passing array to child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to learn react with typescript am not sure why I am receiving this error.

I have my CardApp:

```
public state = {
    cards: []
};


public render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Form onSubmit={this.addNewCard}/>
            <CardList cards={this.state.cards}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The CardList is:

```
const CardList = (props: ICard[]) => {
    return (
        <div>            
            { props.map((card: ICard) => <Card key={card.id} {...card} />) }   
        </div>
    )
}
```

> With this I receive an error Type '{ cards: never[]; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ICard[]'.   Type '{ cards:
>   never[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ICard[]'.
>       Property 'length' is missing in type '{ cards: never[]; }'.

However, if I create a ICards interface:

```
interface ICards {
    cards: ICard[]
}
```

And use that then CardList is:

```
const CardList = (props: ICards) => {
    return (
        <div>            
            { props.cards.map((card: ICard) => <Card key={card.id} {...card} />) }
        </div>
    )
}
```

This works fine, but I was under the impression that `<CardList cards={this.state.cards}/>` was passing an array and not an object with an array property and so the `ICards` interface was not necessary.

Comment: The `props` object is not the `cards` array, but the `cards` key in the `props` object is. Have you tried `const CardList = (props: { cards: ICard[] })`?

Comment: Yep this is it. I didn't realize that it was always an object. Thank you. If you write and answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `props` object is not the `cards` array, but the `cards` key in the `props` object is.

You can write it like this:

```
const CardList = (props: { cards: ICard[] }) => {
  return (
    <div>{props.map((card: ICard) => <Card key={card.id} {...card} />)}</div>
  );
};
```